# System load and keylock Indicator will not autostart in Linux Mint 17

Tags: cinnamon, autostart, indicator

I just switched to Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon from Ubuntu 14 and I do like the interface more!
After installing I started configuring and adding all apps I use. I installed indicator-keylock and indicator-multiload and they run successfully. However if I add them to startup applications they won't start on user login.
I even tried copying the launcher files from /usr/share/applications to ~/.config/autostart but with no effect either...
Note that when logged in the launcher files do open the apps correctly if I launch them manually. Also I have Dropbox and added Vlc to autostart for testing and they work normally.
After some testing I found that if I write a shell script that just contains:
!#bin/bash
indicator key lock

Make it executable and add this to start up applications the indicator starts up normally....
Any ideas why all this trouble? Anyone successfully installed indicator-keylock on mint 17 cinnamon without this workaround and got auto start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's another hack-ish way of doing this, as long as the .desktop file is located in /etc/xdg/autostart/ you can just append it to /usr/share/cinnamon-session/sessions/cinnamon.session

such as... i want indicator-cpufreq to startup on boot, i checked there's a desktop file here (if there wasn't, i'd locate it and copy it there)
/etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-cpufreq.desktop

then I'd edit /usr/share/cinnamon-session/sessions/cinnamon.session and add indicator-cpufreq; at the end of the "RequiredComponents=" line.

Not sure why cinnamon seems to completely ignore indicators, must be a hardcoded blacklist somewhere.

Comment: chickaroo writes: "Not sure why cinnamon seems to completely ignore indicators, must be a hardcoded blacklist somewhere." -- Damn thing! I've just spent some hours blindly debugging the process of ignoring the "/etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-keylock.desktop" file.  The blacklist seems to be looking for the string "indicator-".  So if you rename the file into "indicator_keylock.desktop" or "keylock-indicator.desktop", you're done : ) ! 

To be debugged further (digged through the logs and source of cinnamon).  BTW, the logs seems to be here: $HOME/.cinnamon/glass.log .  Found it at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't resolve the autostart launcher thing..
What I finally  do to start the file is:
create a script file containig this text:

```
#!/bin/bash
indicator-keylock&
```

give it executable permissions, and add this script to the autostart through startup applications...
Mind the ending & as it starts the process in the background...

Answer (score 0):

I have Linux Mint 17 and it works.
Check Control Panel > Keyboard > Layout > Options if you have some setting in conflict.
I had Use Keyboard Led enabled.

Comment: I couldn't understand if what you suggest is relevant, but I gave it a try... no work.... My problem is that the program keylock-indicator, won't autostart in Mint Cinnamon 17.... Have you got Cinnamon or maybe an other environment such  as MATE??? Anyway thank you for your time.